# XMPPError: not-authorized - auth android

Tags: openfire

i want to send a chat message to group. But i am not able to join that particular room from android application, i am using openfire.. every time i am getting

> XMPPError: not-authorized

auth error when i am trying to join the room.. Please response..
Following are the code:

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
MultiUserChat muc2 = manager.getMultiUserChat("testroom@conference.stag-api.artistaloud.com");
            try {
                muc2.join(fromName);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: have you found any solution for that?